# How to stop floating div at specified point using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to stop a floating (sliding) div when it reaches the bottom of a containing div but it isn't working. The variable `bottom` is the lowest point on the page of the containing div but for some reason doesn't act as it should. Anyone have a better method?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var top = $('#buttonsDiv').offset().top - parseFloat($('#buttonsDiv').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var bottom = $('#mainBody').offset().top + $('#mainBody').height();

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {

        // what the y position of the scroll is
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        var z = y + $('#buttonsDiv').height();

        // whether that's below the form
        if (y >= top && z <= bottom) {
            // if so, add the fixed class
            $('#buttonsDiv').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            // otherwise remove it
            $('#buttonsDiv').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In your `.fixed` class, have you given `bottom: 0;` ?

Comment: i tried adding it and it still didnt work. the problem was finding a way for the scroll function to recognise the bottom of the floating element. I think i've solve that in the code above but getting it to stop at the bottom of the div containing it is baffling me.

Comment: Can you include your html and css and/or a working example?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below conditions:

```
 if (y >= top && z <= bottom) {
    // if so, add the fixed class
    $('#buttonsDiv').addClass('fixed');
 } else if(z > bottom) {
    // otherwise remove it
    $('#buttonsDiv').removeClass('fixed').addClass('absolute');
 } else {
    // otherwise remove it
    $('#buttonsDiv').removeClass('fixed');
 }
```

Once you scroll past the container DIV (#mainBody), the floating DIV (#buttonsDiv) should be positioned 'absolute' to the bottom of the container DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Simply defining a margin-bottom with floating div or padding-bottom with external div in this case should help. I have used a similar thing in the following website: www.emotionstorm.com to stop the shopping cart below the top banner.
Please let me know if you need help for a similar code.